# How to capture when user presses "Search Soft key" in android

Tags: android

How to capture when user presses "Search Soft key" in android.

Can we do it in `onKeyDown()` and checking the keycode?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are right. You can check for the key code that is given in the following list.

And prefer to check this onKeyUp.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SEARCH

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Activity` code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    if ( event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH )
    {
        // Catch the search 
        // do something
        // return true to consume press or false to pass it on
    }
    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event ); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers. Actually both of you've answered my question correctly. But only thing was that I didn't ask my question properly. 
In fact, I was trying to capture search softkey while a progress dialog was shown or alert dialog was shown. In those cases, if write the above code in our activity it was not getting called and that exactly was my issue.
Anyway it got solved when I addded this same piece of code for alert dialog and progress dialog separately. So problem was that when those dialogs were shown, the search softkey even was not even reaching my activity.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this for capturing the search softkey when progress dialog is showing and it worked fine for me:

```
progressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
            KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```